# Search history list length

Tags: windows

Is there a way to increase the list showing past searches in windows explorer. Right now it's at 3 items of first focus, and I'd like more. I know it keeps more since if I type something is shows new items matching what I typed. Note: I'm not referring to the search results but the keywords in the actual search box showed in a drop list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to increase the number of searches to more than 3 when you
click on search, but a workaround is to type the first letter of a
previous search. Explorer will then show the last 3 searches starting with
that letter. The more letters you type, the closer the shown words
will be to matching the previous search you're looking for.

As long as you don't clear your search history, you could have an almost
unlimited number of past searches in your history.